# npx react-native-asset isn't giving any output

Tags: react-native, npm, fonts

I am trying to add custom fonts to my app. I tried everything on the internet but nothing works. However, I think that the only thing that works on React Native 0.70.5 is linking assets using `npx react-native-asset`.

I tried making `react-native.config.jsfile`, then using `npx react-native-asset`. However, it just doesn't give any output and resets the command prompt. I even tried Cmder and Windows PowerShell. Nothing works they all reset.

my react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets'],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the exect location of the font's TTF or OTF file.

Update `react-native.config.js` file like this.

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], // stays the same
};
```

Put the font files in `project>>assets>>fonts` folder

After that run command `npx react-native-asset`

Probabily you will get the results.

Comment: Yes. It worked thank you very much... I somehow didn't even need to run react-native-asset it just worked as soon as I changed './assets' to './assets/fonts/'